# Separating Bootstrap Div's in a grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't add a right margin to separate these `div` elements without causing the second to move to a new line.

https://codepen.io/jvern22/pen/GwQpgZ

I have 2 row's with 4 col's in this format;

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
</div>
```

I haven't set the elements to `block` or `inline`

I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's nest your div inside col-lg-6. Something like that

```
    <div class="col-lg-6">  
      <div class="features-box wow fadeInLeft f-box-icon1 p-5">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 features-box-icon">
          <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
          <h3>Picture & Video Tours</h3>
            <p>
              We will visit you with our equipment and create the tour that you want! A photo tour allows your customers to make their own way round your special place, we can add as many notes and information as you want. A video tour can be used to give a guided tour even with your own voiceover.
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Then add margin to you features-box class. Also what was your point adding background image to before selector? Is it not easier to add this property simpy to f-box-icon class?

In addition, you repeat your code. The code for the before selector is practically the same in 4 places. The difference is only in the backgroun-image.